# ClickOnce and redirected start menu

Tags: clickonce, remote-desktop, terminal-services

How does one deploy a ClickOnce app in a system that has a local profile but a redirected start menu?  A client is getting the following error and claims that his session is a local session and not a terminal session, but that his start menu has both local and remote apps included in it:

```
ERROR SUMMARY
                Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
                * Activation of C:\Users\userid\Downloads\App.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
                                + Access to the path '\\Server\StartCtrx$\Testing\Programs\Org\App' is denied.
```

The app itself installs fine (the actual files are present in the AppData\Local\Apps\2.0 folder structure), just not the shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

Set your app up to run online only.

Under install mode and settings:
Select The application is available online only

This will not put an icon on the start menu and the client will always run from the URL.

note: only do this is your app always runs online

Answer (score 0):

The user might not have privileges to add the app to their start menu. You can try creating it yourself when the app starts up. Here's an [article](https://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2009/04/07/creating-a-desktop-shortcut-for-a-click-once-application/) showing how to do that.